# Specify fields in the response

Tags: json, rest, github, github-api

is there a way to specifiy what fields I need in the response? The response is massive and it would be nice to cut the size down for the sake of speed...
I'm using the GitHub REST API v3.

Cheers

Comment: Hi @azatoth, I would like to suggest editing the question and adding more details as it's not clearly visible what you've tried and where exactly help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Github GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) which gives you the ability to specify the fields to be included in the response.

For instance the following will search the first 10 repo with query `language:c`. The result will only have the name of the repo and creation date :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "language:c", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22language%3Ac%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%2010)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositoryCount%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, I know it's doable w/ GraphQL but looks like it's not possible using REST.